# How to match exact string from text file in Batch?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Text file content :

> {"progress":"30","type":"info","message":"Retrieving site specific
>   information from management
>   system."},"2":{"progress":"2","type":"info","message":"Auto
>   Installation
>   initiated."},"5":{"progress":"20.25","type":"info","message":"Checking
>   connectivity to Internet and management
>   system."}},"install_progress":0,"logFileName":"FWF_2018-4-5_12_58_57.log"},"token":"gDDJ7uZx"}

Matching String : `Auto Install is completed`

I am using this code :

```
findstr /c "Auto Install is completed" "test.txt"

if %errorlevel%==0 (

    echo ERROR:Auto Install is completed!
    SET vaildJSONData=0

)
```

Problem : Above code returns true even if this string does not exist

Please assist me.

Answer (score 2):

According to findstr's help:

> /C:string  Uses specified string as a literal search string.

So try with a colon after `/c` like this:

`findstr /c:"Auto Install is completed" "test.txt"`

If you don't do this it simply ignores the `/c`.

Answer (score 0):

There's absolutely no need to use `FindStr` for a basic string search, when `Find` can do the job perfectly well:

```bat
Find /I "Auto Install is completed"<"file.json">Nul&&(Set "validJSONData=0"
    Echo ERROR:Auto Install is completed!)
```